# Solving Large Summations

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

So I'm aware that I can solve simple summations like:
$\sum_{i=1}^{5} (2)/(i(i+2)$

By just pluging in i = 1 to 5 and summing up the values,
but how would I go about approaching something like this?
$\sum_{i=1}^{100} (2)/(i(i+2))$

Or if the numerator changed to a 3 (as well as a denominator), would it be the same process in solving it?

I'm really not sure how to approach this, this is in a discrete math class, not calculus, so partial fractions would probably not be the most optimal of solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, partial fractions work just fine:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac2{k(k+2)}&=\sum_{k=1}^{100}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac1{k+2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac1k-\sum_{k=3}^{102}\frac1k\\
&=\frac11+\frac12-\frac1{101}-\frac1{102}\;,
\end{align*}$$

since the $k=3$ through $k=100$ terms cancel out.

Comment: Just wondering how you knew to separate it into 1/k - 1/k+2 in the first line?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: @user20842454566: Partly experience: I can see that I’ll get fractions with denominators $k$ and $k+2$ and numerators of the same magnitude but opposite sign when I decompose it into partial fractions, and that means that I’ll get a lot of telescoping.

Comment: Also, if I wanted a final answer (From the 4 fractions remaining), how would I go about finding a LCD? Or would I just multiply them all together?

Comment: Use a calculator, or just leave it like that, or do the common denominator trick.

Comment: I'm not permitted to using a calculator in this class.

Comment: @user20842454566: Whatever seems most convenient. I’d first find $$\frac1{101}+\frac1{102}=\frac{203}{10302}$$ and then subtract that from $$\frac32=\frac{15453}{10302}$$ to get $$\frac{15250}{10302}=\frac{7625}{5151}\;,$$ if I’ve not loused up the arithmetic anywhere. All of the necessary arithmetic is easily done by hand; the longest calculation is $101\cdot102=10302$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{1}{i(i+1)} = \dfrac1i-\dfrac1{i+1}$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{2}{i(i+1)}=\frac{1}{i}+\frac{-1}{i+2}$

so $\sum_{i=1}^{100}[\frac{1}{i}+\frac{-1}{i+2}]=(1-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5})+...=1+\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4})+...+(\frac{1}{100}-\frac{1}{100})-\frac{1}{101}-\frac{1}{102}=1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{101}-\frac{1}{102}$

Answer (score 0):

By using Telescope Rule

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac2{k(k+2)}&=\sum_{k=1}^{100}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{100}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}+\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{k+2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{100}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{100}\left(\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{k+2}\right)\\
&=1-\frac1{100+1}+\frac{1}{1+1}-\frac{1}{100+2}=1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{101}-\frac{1}{102};,
\end{align*}$$